# PostgreSQL Window Function "column must appear in the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a leaderboard of summed user scores from a list of user score entries. A single user can have more than one entry in this table.

I have the following table:

```
rewards
=======
user_id | amount
```

I want to add up all of the `amount` values for given users and then rank them on a global leaderboard. Here's the query I'm trying to run:

`SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) AS score, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) FROM rewards;`

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "rewards.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) AS score, rank() OVER (PARTITION...
```

Isn't `user_id` already in an "aggregate function" because I'm trying to partition on it? The PostgreSQL manual shows the following entry which I feel is a direct parallel of mine, so I'm not sure why mine's not working:

`SELECT depname, empno, salary, avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname) FROM empsalary;`

They're not grouping by `depname`, so how come theirs works?

For example, for the following data:

```
user_id | score
===============
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 5
3 | 1
```

I would expect the following output (I have made a "tie" between users 1 and 2):

```
user_id | SUM(score) | rank
===========================
1 | 5 | 1
2 | 5 | 1
3 | 1 | 3
```

So user 1 has a total score of 5 and is ranked #1, user 2 is tied with a score of 5 and thus is also rank #1, and user 3 is ranked #3 with a score of 1.

Comment: what result you want?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` user_id since it's not being aggregated. Then you can rank by `SUM(score)` descending as you want;

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6ae1/1)**

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(score), RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC)
FROM rewards 
GROUP BY user_id;

 user_id | sum | rank
---------+-----+------
       1 |   5 |    1
       2 |   5 |    1
       3 |   1 |    3
```

Comment: This looks like the simplest and most direct approach. I think I need to improve my understanding of exactly what "PARTITION BY" does. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `PARTITION BY` works as a `GROUP BY` for each row. In this case you need `GROUP BY`  because you start with 4 rows and will end with 3. In the question case if you remove the `SUM()`  the windows function will return all 4 rows

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between window functions and aggregate functions. Some functions can be used both as a window function and an aggregate function, which can cause confusion. Window functions can be recognized by the OVER clause in the query.

The query in your case then becomes, split in doing first an aggregate on user_id followed by a window function on the total_amount.

`SELECT user_id, total_amount, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_amount DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) total_amount
  FROM table
  GROUP BY user_id
) q
ORDER BY total_amount DESC`

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
    SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) ....
                   ^^^
                   agreagted function (not window function)
    ....
    FROM .....
```

You need

```
    GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: If I group by user_id, they're all ranked 1. The partition is effectively grouping them, right? Am I not understanding how that's supposed to work?

Comment: Sorry, I just answer what is wrong. I m testing the right way to do it now :P